# get all files from directory as blob on browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

I am currently fetching single file from public folder of my app as below

```
import Pdf from "../assets/sample/Sample.pdf";
const response = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: Pdf,
    responseType: "blob",
});
```

I would like to get the content of whole of sample directory where multiple files are stored.

please look at the path of pdf where its stored in sample directory.

i am trying to find out what should be the response type be for a directory?

i could achieve by making multiple calls, but i want am trying to find a way to do in single call.

```
const getFilesFromFolder = async () => {
    const response = await axios.all([
        makeRequestForSingleFile(Pdf),
        makeRequestForSingleFile("/src/assets/sample/Sample.docx"),
        makeRequestForSingleFile("/src/assets/sample/Sample.ppt"),
    ]);
    return response.map(obj => obj.data);
};
```

Comment: Do you have a list of all of the files that you're trying to fetch?  Or a way to get that list from the server?  The process doesn't change, no matter how many files you want to get.  Each one is an AJAX operation to get the file.  If what you have works then you just need to repeat it for other files.

Comment: i didnt want multiple calls, i will add that code above though.

i do not all file names 

any way to do without repeating calls?

Comment: Any given HTTP request is one request, one response.  What exactly are you looking to request from the server?  A `.zip` file of the contents of the directory?  Something else?

Comment: i have a react app, i want to react doc,pdf etc files from public asset folder.
i want to use them as blob further to process them.

Comment: Well, if you want multiple files via AJAX then you make multiple requests to receive multiple responses.